# Headless Chromedriver add proxy username and password

Tags: selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I'm running headless chromedriver on python selenium, but am struggling to add a new proxy argument which has a username and password.

On an existing proxy I have which doesn't require a username or password this works fine:

```
proxy = '123.45.678.901'
options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
```

How now do I add arguments for a username and password? I've searched around but couldn't find an answer.

Many thanks